# Add/modify overlay feaures using Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I'm using Google API, ExtJs 3.21, Java for my application.
I have already done the vector layer creation and modification features using Openlayers.
But, now i have to convert into Google API.

Can we create overlay / vector layers creation, 
call overlay layer(by name or by id), 
add values, edit values, delete values in overlay layer using Google API.

Please guide me to do this with some sample examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the google map API reference for the overlays might help to convert your vector layers to [google maps overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)